# Why is Taylor's ethic of authenticity not a middle position or a tradeoff?

Tags: ethics

<sub>Source: p 470 Bottom, [*Introducing Philosophy for Canadians: A Text with Integrated Readings*](https://www.amazon.ca/Introducing-Philosophy-Canadians-Integrated-Readings/dp/0195430964) (2011 1 ed).

[Primary Source:](https://books.google.com/books?id=f11Q-RNvmSEC&lpg=PA23&ots=e5b21-7g1z&dq=%22the%20picture%20i%20am%20offering%20is%20rather%20that%22&pg=PA23#v=onepage&q=%22the%20picture%20i%20am%20offering%20is%20rather%20that%22&f=false) p 22 Bottom - 23 Top, *The Ethics of Authenticit*y by Charles Taylor</sub>

> What I am suggesting is a position distinct from 
>   both boosters and knockers of contemporary culture. 
>   Unlike the boosters, I do not believe that everything 
>   is as it should be in this culture. Here I tend to agree 
>   with the knockers. But unlike them, I think that 
>   authenticity should be taken seriously as a moral ideal. **[1.]** I differ also from the various middle positions, **[End of 1.]**
>   which hold that there are some good things in this 
>   culture (like greater freedom for the individual), but 
>   that these come at the expense of certain dangers 
>   (like a weakening of the sense of citizenship), so that 
>   one's best policy is to find the ideal point of trade-off 
>   between advantages and costs.
>     The picture I am offering is rather that of an ideal 
>   that has degraded but that is very worthwhile in 
>   itself, and indeed, I would like to say, unrepudiable 
>   by moderns. So what we need is neither root-and-branch condemnation nor uncritical praise; and not 
>    a carefully balanced trade-off.  What we need is a 
>   work of retrieval, through which this ideal can help 
>   us restore Our practice.

Per 1, why is not Taylor's position above really some middle position between the boosters and knockers?

Comment: Are you suggesting 2 contradicts 1? It seems to me 2 is a reinforcement or recapitulation of the 1. As to why his position is not "knocker" nor "booster" nor "anything in between": it's because he sees a [third path](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TakeAThirdOption). In particular, he appears to a bit of a Utopist: from this passage, he seems to believe the ideal is possible, and the culture has already got its hands on it. It's just that ideal has become a little debased and grimy. All it needs is to be polished up, to have the bad elements removed.

Comment: @DanBron Yes; I was implying that 2 contradicts 1; but I did not recognise this implication until you had indicated it!

Comment: If you moved your beginning-of-2.-marker one word to he left, the contradiction evaporates. In both cases the author is saying his solution is *not* a happy middle ground. That nothing need to be traded off, necessarily. Determining  whether his position is plausible or elaborating on its actual nature, I'll leave to my better philosophically-equipped colleagues.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks; I misread it then. I have removed Q2 that you have successfully resolved!

Comment: Cool. Just in case it's not already clear, the introductory paragraph you quote *asserts* that the author has found some beneficial option which is not a middle ground between boosters and knockers, but it doesn't really describe it, much less justify it. Presumably (a part of) the balance of the work is intended to do just that. But it's impossible to tell you whether his claim is appropriate or plausible, or even what it is, from just this quotation. Someone would already have to be familiar with the author or this particular work.